# what's the safe way to use rsync without password prompt in shell script

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords

I want to sync a remote directory to local with rsync command, my local server is redhat enterprise linux 6.5.

I googled, but only found tutorials how to set up ssh key with empty passphrase.

I followed one tutorial from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/rsync-over-ssh-without-password/) , and it worked, calling rsync will not ask for password any more.

```
rsync -avzhe --min-size=1 ssh user@host:/somedir ~/backup
```

but, our system is in production environment, I think it may be not good to use ssh-key with empty passphrase from the security perspective. Correct me if I am wrong, but if I am right, how to safely use rsync without password prompt ?

Comment: There is really no other way. Without password means without password. You just have to properly secure the private key.